# VBA Need to check if each cell in column Y is from a list of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi trying to check if each cell in column Y is from a list of another sheet. The result of vlookup function is always "false". I am not sure why. Please advise

```
Sub CheckDropDown()
   Dim MyStringVar As Variant, i As Integer
   Dim Lookup_Range As Range, lastRow As Integer, ws As Worksheet
   Set Lookup_Range = Worksheets("Lists").Range("C1:C21")
   lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
   For i = 2 To lastRow
     On Error Resume Next
    'MyStringVar = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =   "=VLOOKUP(Cells(i,25),Lists!C[-25],1)"
    MyStringVar = ActiveCell.Formula = "VLookup(Cells(i, 25).value, Lookup_Range, 1, False)"

    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case Cells(i, 25).value
      Case IsEmpty(MyStringVar)
       ' do nothing
      Case Is = MyStringVar

      Case Is <> MyStringVar
      ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 25).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 5)
    End Select
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to remove any vba from the quotes: `ActiveCell.Formula = "VLookup(" & Cells(i, 25).Address(0,0) & "," & Lookup_Range.address(1,1) & ", 1, False)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that you get this unexpected result because you are not writing a valid formula in the ActiveCell. A valid formula would be

```
=VLOOKUP(Y2, 'Lists'!C1:C21, 1, FALSE)
```

So create your code in such a way that that is what is between the quotes "".

If you put there a valid formula, that is the same as the one you tried writing in your excel-sheet yourself, then it will work. Now you're mixing excel-formula in the interface with programming language.

So something like this:

```
Dim myFormula As String
myFormula = "=VLOOKUP("

Dim columnLetter As String
columnLetter = "Y"

Dim tmpFormula As String
For i = 2 to x

  tmpFormula = myFormula & columnLetter & i & ", 'lists'!C1:C25, 1, FALSE)"

  .. test formula .. etc.
Next i
```

Success

ps. Don't remember anymore if you require the '=' in front of the formula, so just try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of combining formulas and code when you can solve the problem with just one of them, so I'd recommend you to use pure code to check the values using this piece of code as base.

```
Sub CheckDropDown()
    Dim MyStringVar As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim Lookup_Range, cel As Range, lastRow As Integer, check As Boolean
    Set Lookup_Range = Worksheets("Lists").Range("C1:C21")
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For Each cel In Lookup_Range
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 25) = cel.Value Then
                check = True: Exit For
            Else
                check = False
            End If
        Next
        If check Then
            'The cell is on the lookupRange
        Else
            'The cell is NOT on the lookupRange
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 25).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 5)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Xavier Navarro 's code is working great. If I want to count how many cells of value are not in the list in the end and reflect the count in the msgbox , how should I do it?